# Cannot access jira after fresh install

Tags: connection, installation, jira

I'm having troubles accessing jira after a fresh install.

If I wget localhost:8080 from the machine where jira runs, I'll get an html file.

If I try to access IP_ADDRESS:8080 from another computer, the browser response with a "Cant connect to..."

If I nmap my jira machine, it says the following:

```
Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-04-29 11:28 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000017s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

I'm not a linux expert, so I dont know much about iptables and stuff like that.

I also checked my access_log of the tomcat installation, but the file is empty.

Anyone know, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

It was a firewall problem:

```
[root@testing logs]# iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             
3    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
5    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere     --> I removed this line
```

Answer (score 0):

You should've executed this line instead:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT